# Is it possible to make plastic out of fibres?

Tags: materials

Can we make plastic, especially bio-plastic from vegetable and fruit fibres?

Comment: We kinda can, but the result is not called "plastic".

Answer (score 3):

Sure; it is one of the oldest "plastics": [cellophane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cellophane) and [rayon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rayon).

It is not difficult to demonstrate, though care must be taken with the somewhat poisonous [cuprammonium](http://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/ac60039a019?journalCode=ancham) solvent.

Other plastics can be made from substituted cellulose, such as [cellulose acetate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cellulose_acetate)... what could be more "organic" than vinegar and wood pulp?

Comment: On a way one can see paper as a polymer hybrid material, too.